# Как передать переменную в пользовательское поле Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Есть портал на битрикс. Нужно передавать значение переменной в пользовательское поле. Мб кто-то ткнет меня носом в это? Искал искал, не нашел.
Поле вида UF_FIELD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = new CUser;
$fields = array(
  "UF_FIELD_NAME" => $vac,
);
$user->Update($uID, $fields);
```

Примерно вот так. Переменные и название полей, естественно, у каждого свои.